# PyTorch - TypeError: forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pytorch

I do not understand where this error comes from, the number of arguments to the model seems correct, below is my model:

```py
class MancalaModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, n_inputs=16, n_outputs=16):
        super().__init__()

        n_neurons = 256

        def create_block(n_in, n_out):
            block = nn.ModuleList()
            block.append(nn.Linear(n_in, n_out))
            block.append(nn.ReLU())
            return block

        self.blocks = nn.ModuleList()
        self.blocks.append(create_block(n_inputs, n_neurons))
        for _ in range(6):
            self.blocks.append(create_block(n_neurons, n_neurons))

        self.actor_block = nn.ModuleList()
        self.critic_block = nn.ModuleList()
        for _ in range(2):
            self.actor_block.append(create_block(n_neurons, n_neurons))
            self.critic_block.append(create_block(n_neurons, n_neurons))

        self.actor_block.append(create_block(n_neurons, n_outputs))
        self.critic_block.append(create_block(n_neurons, 1))

        self.apply(init_weights)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.blocks(x)
        actor = F.softmax(self.actor_block(x))
        critics = self.critic_block(x)
        return actor, critics
```

Then I create an instance and make a forward pass with random number

```py
model = MancalaModel()
x = model(torch.rand(1, 16))
```

Then I got the TypeError saying the number of arguments is not correct:

```
      2 model = MancalaModel()
----> 3 x = model(torch.rand(1, 16))
      4 # summary(model, (16,), device='cpu')
      5 

d:\environments\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

D:\UOM\Year3\AI & Games\KalahPlayer\agents\model_agent.py in forward(self, x)
     54 
     55     def forward(self, x):
---> 56         x = self.blocks(x)
     57         actor = F.softmax(self.actor_block(x))
     58         critics = self.critic_block(x)

d:\environments\python\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

TypeError: forward() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**
You are trying to `forward` through [`nn.ModuleList`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ModuleList.html#torch.nn.ModuleList) - this is not defined.
You need to convert `self.blocks` to [`nn.Sequential`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Sequential.html#torch.nn.Sequential):

```py
        def create_block(n_in, n_out):
            # do not work with ModuleList here either.
            block = nn.Sequential(
              nn.Linear(n_in, n_out),
              nn.ReLU()
            )
            return block

        blocks = []  # simple list - not a member of self, for temporal use only.
        blocks.append(create_block(n_inputs, n_neurons))
        for _ in range(6):
            blocks.append(create_block(n_neurons, n_neurons))
        self.blocks = nn.Sequential(*blocks)  # convert the simple list to nn.Sequential
```

---

I was expecting you to get `NotImplementedError`, and not this `TypeError`, because your `self.blocks` is of type `nn.ModuleList` and its `forward` method throws `NotImplementedError`. I just made a [pull request](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/48785) to fix this confusing issue.
*Update (April 22nd, 2021):* the PR [was merged](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/48785#issuecomment-824241977). In future versions you should see `NotImplementedError` when calling `nn.ModuleList` or `nn.ModuleDict`.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue exists in torch 1.7.1

Comment: @RakshitKothari the status of this pull request is "stuck" - it conflicts with unrelated issues with torch scripting. feel free to comment there and draw attention to it from pytorch's developers.

Comment: @RakshitKothari this PR was merged on April 22nd. For more recent pytorch versions you should get `NotImplementedError`. I confirmed that with version 1.9.0